# Discord.py "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'channel'"

Tags: python, discord.py

I haven't touched anything in my code it was working before now it isn't what do I do?

My Code:

```
  @commands.command(aliases=['Purge', "Clear", "clear"])
  @commands.has_permissions(manage_messages = True)
  async def purge(self,message,ctx,amount=2):
    LOG_CHANNEL = self.client.get_channel(898771125482455041)
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.send(f":white_check_mark: Cleared `{amount}` Messages!")
    
    embed=nextcord.Embed(title="Messages Cleared", color=0xf2ec00)
    embed.add_field(name="Responsible Mod:", value=f"{ctx.author.name}", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Channel:", value=f"{ctx.channel.mention}", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Amount:", value=f"{amount}", inline=False)
    await LOG_CHANNEL.send(embed=embed)
```

The Error:
`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'channel'`

Comment: Please provide entire stack trace so its easier to debug. Though from my guess, it's the first line you use ctx, `ctx.channel.purge`, because if it was any further down it wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Also provide, e.g. how you are calling this async function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your arguments are switched around, `ctx` needs to be the first argument, except in a class where it needs to be the second, after `self`. If you swap `message` and `ctx` around it should work.

```py
async def purge(self, ctx, message, amount=2):
```

However, I'm not sure why you have a `message` argument in the first place, since you  do not seem to use it anywhere. You can just delete it if you are not using it to avoid a missing argument error.

```py
async def purge(self, ctx, amount=2):
```